# Importprivkey's "label" - is it the same as an account?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, json-rpc, api, bitcoin-core-accounts

The "[importprivkey](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)" API call allows one to import a private key and save it with a label. Is the "label" in the API call synonymous with an account used in the wallet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though the terminiology is unclear, in code "label" and "account" are the same thing:

`importprivkey` function ([`src/rpcdump.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/738835d7b8ab80bd0812805f197471c54c72d7f9/src/rpcdump.cpp#L60)):

```
pwalletMain->SetAddressBookName(vchAddress, strLabel);
```

from `getnewaddress` function ([`src/rpcwallet.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ad525e9c8fa2b15f1afe6b7284de638a090e891a/src/rpcwallet.cpp#L112)):

```
pwalletMain->SetAddressBookName(keyID, strAccount);
```